# PFLoginViewController How to switch between login screen and main page? Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller, pfloginviewcontroller

I am trying to use the PFLoginViewController to create a simple login screen for my app.  The problem I am running into is the ability to switch between the login screen and the main page of the app based on `.currentUser()` output.

I was able to accomplish this in Objective C using this method:

> AppDelegate.m

[image]
[image]

> LogInViewController.m

[image]

[image]

I'm using Swift in my new app and am trying to duplicate the method I used in Objective C but I'm getting this error and the simulator is all black.]

[image]

Here's what my code looks like in swift.

> AppDelegate

[image]

> LoginVC

[image]

I have done some looking into this and I've seen that it's an issue with `viewDidLoad` instead of using `viewWillAppear` but I don't see the application to my issue because it worked in Objective C in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and also the delegate methods of PFLoginViewController aren't called in `viewDidLoad`.

Any clues as to what's my big mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue I was having.

> AppDelegate

[image]

Instead of `presentViewController` I used `pushViewController`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the Obj-C you're getting the navigation controller from the window (the root view controller), so it's presented. In the swift you're creating a new navigation controller, and then you might again create another new navigation controller with a root view controller. Neither of these are presented so trying to use them for much other than presenting them won't work. This is a significant logical change between the 2 code samples. There is nothing to stop you following the same approach in each language and it should resolve your error.

Comment: For the Objective C code I'm guessing that you're referring to this snippet?     `UINavigationController *navVC = (UINavigationController *) self.window.rootViewController;`  I know that this piece of code gets the navigation controller from the storyboard then sets it as the rootViewController but how do you do this in swift?

Comment: Yes, I am. No, it doesn't. The nav controller has already been unpacked from the storyboard and set into the window as the root view controller, this code gets that root view controller. The code to do it in swift is basically identical because of the dot notation.